# Change Android Smart TV Box settings from tablet to TV

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, android-tv, smart-tv

I bought [this](http://www.amazon.de/VicTsing-Octa-Core-Unterst%C3%BCtzen-Bluetooth-Entertainment/dp/B01BSIYDEQ/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1457880454&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=vicsang%20android) Android based Smart TV Box from Amazon. It's complicated to navigate within the interface because the Android settings of the box are for **tablet** instead for **TV**. 
That causes the problem that apps that are TV optimized (Netflix..) display the tablet interface instead of the TV one. 
Is it possible to change the box settings to TV?

Details:

- Android 5.1
  Octa-Core 64bits CPU - Rockchip 3368 Octa-Core 64-Bit
  ARM Coretex-A53 up to 1,5 GHz, 2G RAM.